# How to divide a spatial line into smaller segments of equal length in R?

Tags: r, line, gis, shapefile

I am working with spatial data in R and I'm having some trouble. The shapefile I am using represents the boundaries of different countries. I was able to isolate the border between two specific countries and now I want to cut/split this border which is a spatial line into 3 different segments of equal length. Do you have any idea of how I can do that? None of the solutions I've found online seems to work.

Best regards,
Sam.

Comment: `lwgeom` as discussed here [linestring split](https://github.com/r-spatial/lwgeom/issues/16), as an approach `lwgeom::st_linesubstring`. Welcome to Stackoverflow.